# Looking for an 80’s fantasy book series

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I am looking for an 80’s fantasy book series.  The covers of the books and the books themselves were pinks and oranges. I think there may have been more than 5 but less than 15.  The one I remember had a reaper on the cover so it was not a teen girl series. I remember the covers all having the same front with title and then a fantasy sci fy picture in an oval under the title.

I am not sure but I also think it was YA.  I saw them in the old mall bookstores.

It is quite hard because this was 35 years ago and I was 10 at the time. The book stores were either B Dalton or Walden books. Walden I think as it was in our local US mall. I had purchased the first book of the Iron Tower trilogy by Dennis McTiernan so 84 or 85.

The books I remember were near where these books were. The reaper I remember did not have a scythe but maybe had a hand out. I do not remember the blurb but thought they were a series.

Comment: I take it you never actually read the books? That's going to make it tricky to pin down. By "a reaper on the cover," do you mean someone in a dark hooded robe, brandishing a scythe? And did the "reaper" appear to be an animated skeleton? I'm trying to visualize this, since I was a youngster who went shopping for SF/Fantasy paperbacks in the 1980s, so I might have seen these books at some point . . .

Comment: Any chance it was the Incarnations of Immortality series?
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-yJmlYHFpQEU/UWWMMzI_scI/AAAAAAAAAjc/jZbrvgNYXK0/s1600/IMG_3538.JPG

Comment: Unfortunately, until you provide some idea of the books' contents, this question is going to be unanswerable.

Comment: In what country did you see these books? If you read them, can you explain what you remember of the story? Can you provide any more details at all?

Comment: @Liesmith: I was going to suggest *Incarnations of Immortality* until I saw you already has.  :-)

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I was going to comment that I was going to suggest *Incarnations of Immortality* and then I saw that you already did

Answer (score 1):

Any chance it was [*The Belgariad*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1046)?  There weren't *that* many fantasy series in 80s of at least 5 books with pastel covers...

Cover from ISFDB:

[image: Cover of Pawn of Prophecy]

Comment: Because ISFDB doesn't have HTTPS, that image couldn't be displayed; I uploaded it to Stack Imgur instead. Also, please upload images to it even if they have HTTPS so they don't break later.

Comment: @Stormblessed Thanks, I couldn't figure out how to do it properly from my phone.

Comment: yeah it's lame; it doesn't upload when you add photos, instead just putting them in. I always use the full site, which scales well on posts at least.